# encodeURIComponent not working in select list

Tags: jquery, select, encodeuricomponent

I'm trying to make a function that puts some elements in a select list if these elements are not in it already. My header is set for an ISO encoding, but if my "subject" contains a currency symbol such as "€", I get a question mark "?" instead of it in the list.

Here's my code:

```
            $.each(subjects, function(key, subject) 
        {
            if (select.find('option[value=\"' + subject + '\"]').length === 0 && subject!="") 
            {
                /*if (selectList == "produitcartesien")
                    {
                        alert(subject);
                    }*/
                 //Ajouter la nouvelle catégorie dans la liste
                   $('<option>', {
                     value: subject,
                     text: subject
                     }).appendTo(select);

                 if (colored==true && !(selectionOf("subjectslist")=="" && selectionOf("relationslist")=="" && selectionOf("complementslist")==""
                         && selectionOf("subjectCategories")=="" && selectionOf("complementcategories")==""))
                     {

                         $('#' + selectList + ' option[value="'+ subject +'"]').css('color', 'red');
                     }
            }
        });
```

I tried

```
value: encodeURIComponent(subject);
text: encodeURIComponent(subject);
```

But it displays the subjects with awkward characters such as 2%2C3F...
What can I do to display my string with the currency symbols?
Thank you in advance.

Edit: Sorry, the problem described above was wrong. My variable was already set with the question mark before. Here's the real question, that remains unanswered at this time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185309/use-encodeuricomponent-with-jsp

If someone can help...
Thank you.

Comment: Be sure you saved your file in the matching ISO format also. By the way, those "awkward characters" are [URL encoding (percent-encoding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using:

```
value: decodeURIComponent("50 %E2%82%AC");
text: decodeURIComponent("50 %E2%82%AC");
```

The results will be "50 €"

Comment: The problem is, my value is not a constant, but a variable.
In my example, the value is 2,38€, but it could be some other amount or currency...
Your answer inspired me to try decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(subject)) but it didn't work either...